# Sendmail is canonicalizing domain name from CNAME

Tags: sendmail

I have an old mail server that I recently replaced.

The replacement is delivering mail as expected, but there is an odd quirk.  I have a variety of aliases that deliver mail to a list of people.  When `user@example.com` sends an e-mail via Outlook to `list@example.com`, there is a mapping for that Mail-User to an external address called `list@mail.example.com`, so the `To:` gets rewritten and delivered to our mail server.  When `newserver.example.com` gets the message, it accepts it and delivers it, but rewrites the To: header to `list@newserver.example.com`.

The issue with this is that it breaks the reply-to because it expects `@example.com` and `@mail.example.com`. How can I prevent this from happening? I have a CNAME record in place that `mail.example.com` points to `newserver.example.com`, which makes me think it is mapping it from DNS somehow.  Can I prevent this, or at least force it to use `mail.example.com` or `example.com` instead of `newserver`?

Example of the `sendmail -bt` -- `/try esmtp` test:

```
> /try esmtp list@mail.example.com
Trying envelope recipient address list@mail.example.com for mailer esmtp
canonify           input: list @ mail . example . com
Canonify2          input: list < @ mail . example . com >
Canonify2        returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
canonify         returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
2                  input: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
2                returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
EnvToSMTP          input: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
PseudoToReal       input: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
PseudoToReal     returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
MasqSMTP           input: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
MasqSMTP         returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
EnvToSMTP        returns: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
final              input: list < @ newserver . example . com . >
final            returns: list @ newserver . exemple . com
Rcode = 0, addr = list@newserver.example.com
```

Comment: Just discovered FEATURE(`nocanonify') but this partially solves it, but now messages to e.g list@oldserver.domain.com won't get written to list@domain.com (I would like to retain mail.domain.com somehow, or remap specific domains to mail.domain.com)

Comment: Maybe turn on [masquerading](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html) so that newserver rewrites newserver.domain.com to mail.domain.com (or domain.com) on outgoing mail.

Comment: masquerading is enabled, but doesn't seem to be working.  It looks like it is canonifying mail to newserver because of the CNAME but I can't be sure.  Should newserver be a CNAME to mail instead?

Comment: It's possible. sendmail will canonicalize to `$j`, which IIRC defaults to whatever the local system reports as its hostname (normally a fully-qualified domain name). It may call `gethostbyname` to get the canonical name. It's probably better to manually set `j` in the cf file (probably there's a macro for this) to ensure the name you want  rather than rely on CNAMEs.

Comment: Is there a way to properly set $j?

Comment: add `define(confDOMAIN_NAME, domain.com)dnl` to `sendmail.mc` and rebuild.   http://serverfault.com/questions/588342/force-sendmail-to-not-use-machines-hostname-for-local-domain

Comment: That's already defined, and mc is already rebuilt to new sendmail.cf with that

Comment: Can you check that the `Dj` line in `sendmail.cf` is indeed `domain.com`? I don't understand how Canonify2 would rewrite an address to `newserver.domain.com` if `$j` is `domain.com`.

Comment: Yes, the Dj line is set to domain.com. (with a trailing '.').  I'm not sure I understand it either, but the best I can guess is it looks up 'mail.domain.com' and sees that it is a CNAME for newserver.domain.com and then rewrites the address from mail.domain.com to newserver.domain.com which is NOT what we want.  (How does anyone deploy multiple servers and still have it Canonify correctly without disabling canonification?)

Comment: Out of curiousity, do `ping newserver.domain.com`, `ping mail.domain.com`, and `ping domain.com` return the same IP's or different IP's?

Comment: same IPs- mail.domain.com is a CNAME for newserver.domain.com